# Is there a Jenkins build parameter for artifacts?

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I would like to refer to the artifact URL in a deploy job I'm creating.  How can I do that?

For example - when I select a build from the **Build History** I get to the build page.  If I right click on a build artifact, I can copy the link.  The link looks something like:

`h_t_t_p://....../artifact/...../xyz.rpm`

Can I refer to that using a build parameter or environment variable?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to deploy the latest version of the artifact, there is a permalink that you can use:

```
http://jenkins-server/job/job-name/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/path/to/artifact
```